Migration of questions about purely legal terms
I note that the question "What does "hypothecate" mean?" was migrated to English Usage SE.
I'm surprised by that, because this is a highly technical, purely legal term that doesn't seem to be a good fit for English SE and is perfectly normal for Law.SE.
Is there something about what is on topic at Law.SE that I am missing?

I agree that Law.SE was an appropriate place for the question. This is a technical legal term that has much more nuance to its meaning in civil law than naive translation to "mortgage."
Barbara Pierre, "Classification of Property and Conceptions of Ownership in Civil and Common Law" (1997) 28 Revue générale de droit 235:

The nature of the mortgage and the hypothec of immovables are far from similar, and reflect in the common law the absence of, and in the civil law the reliance on, an abstract
concept of ownership.

To explain a hypothec requires explaining the nature of property in civil law.

FYI, I provided an answer that borrows heavily from your answer here at English.SE. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/625168/what-does-hypothecate-mean/625192#625192
